# Derivative of an Integral with a function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

what is $$\frac {d e^{-t/2} \int_t^T e^{u/2} du} {dt}$$? This is a question related to conditional expectation and ito's lemma and I am trying to figure out the dt part on this equation.

do we need to apply chain rule on this? or it simply equals $e^{-t/2}* -e^{t/2} dt$?

Answer (score 0):

It is $-e^{-t/2}\int_t^{T}e^{u/2}du-e^{-t/2}e^{t/2}=-e^{-t/2}\int_t^{T}e^{u/2}du-1$ by product rule and the fact that the derivative of an antiderivative of a function is the function itself.

Comment: so i have to use chain rule in this case?

Comment: I have edited the answer.